# Catch control.setValue action on Storybook (Angular)

Tags: angular, storybook, angular-storybook

The issue is for Angular 9 although the question should be valid for any case.

I have a component that looks more or less as the following:

```
export class MyComponent {
  @Input() config: Config;
  @Input() control: FormControl;
};
```

And function inside the component that do several steps and ends with a this.control.setValue(value);

I want to catch the function using the addon-actions but I was unable to do that since I cant found a way of how to capture the nested event.

I usually do:

```
export const Default: Story<MyComponent > = TEMPLATE.bind({});
FormattersDe.args = {
  config: {
     ...
  },
  control: new FormControl()
};
```

But of course there is no action catched, I also try with:

```
export const Default: Story<MyComponent > = TEMPLATE.bind({});
FormattersDe.args = {
  config: {
     ...
  },
  control: MOCKED_CONTROL
};
const MOCKED_CONTROL = {
   ...new FormControl(),
   setValue: action.setValue
}
```

But it seems since is not on the first level there is no capture there.

Comment: you can subscribe to control.valueChanges, `this.FormattersDe.args.control.valueChanges.subscribe(res=>{...})`.NOTE you can not use the spread operator to "extends" a control `{...new FormControl}` return an object, but the methods of the object dont' execute -you can access to value but can not use, e.g.  setValue()-

Comment: Got a max stack size, but you point me on the proper direction.

Comment: if you use valueChanges to change a validator or to make an updateValueAndValidity, try use {emitEvent:false}

Comment: I dont think that is related because I put the code on a easier func and got the error.
Also I try with "distinctUntilChange()" on the pipe and also got the stack trace.